# How to add new button near the create button in odoo 16 community?

Tags: odoo

I'm new to odoo and i want to add button near odoo create button like in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfiM4.png).
Somebody, please can help  me.
Thank you

i don't find a possibility to implement that in my xml tree view

Comment: You probably forgot the picture?

Answer (score 1):

In tree/list views you can add action buttons next to the create button by defining a header right after the `<tree>` node.

For example from the purchase app of Odoo 16, which adds a button for bills creation:

```xml
<tree string="Purchase Order" decoration-info="state in ['draft', 'sent']" decoration-muted="state == 'cancel'" class="o_purchase_order" js_class="purchase_dashboard_list" sample="1">
    <header>
        <button name="action_create_invoice" type="object" string="Create Bills"/>
    </header>
    <field name="priority" optional="show" widget="priority" nolabel="1"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

Near create button you cannot add from `xml`, if you want that you have to add it from js.

Comment: Please check my question too about this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106389/how-to-create-custom-button-in-odoo-treeview-to-open-windows-file-upload-dialog